using christoffel symbol gives a wrong divergence in spherical coordinate
I am trying to use the following formula for spherical coordinate to find the divergence of a velocity field. The formula reads
$$\nabla_k u^k = (\frac{\partial u^k}{\partial x_k}+ u^j \Gamma_{kj}^i) .$$
In spherical coordinate metric and Christoffel symbol read
$$\begin{align}
 g_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & r^2 & 0\\
  0  & 0 & r^2 \sin^2 \theta
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}$$
$$
 \Gamma_{\phi \theta}^{\phi}=\cot \theta$$
and the scaling factors are $\ell_1=1$, $\ell_2=r$, $\ell_3=r \sin \theta$.
For simplicity let's assume that the only non-zero component of the velocity is $u^2=u_{\theta}$ and $u_{r}=u_{\phi}=0$. As a result the formula for the divergence can be written as
$\boldsymbol{\nabla}_k \textbf{u}^k = (\frac{\partial u^{\theta}}{ \partial \theta}+ u^{\theta} \Gamma_{k \theta}^k) = (\frac{\partial u^{\theta}}{ \partial \theta} + u^{\theta} \cot \theta)$ which is different from the formula for the divergence of the velocity in spherical coordinate with a factor of $q/r$. Could someone please help me understand which step is not correct? In spherical coordinate the divergence reads $\nabla \cdot u=(\frac{\partial u^{\theta}}{ \partial \theta} + u^{\theta} \cot \theta)/r$.

What "formula for the divergence of the velocity in spherical coordinate" are you comparing to? Are you perhaps confusing $u^i$ and $u_i$?

@md2perpe this is the formula I am referring to $\partial_r (r^2 u_r)/r^2$

In that formula, $u_r$ is the coefficient for $\mathbf u$ relative the unit vector $\hat r,$ while in the tensor formula, $u_i$ is relative a (in general) non-ON base.

@md2perpe what do you mean by nonOn base? Is it possible to get the spherical coordinate formula from a general tensor formula? How does the tensor formula needs to be modified t get the spherical coordinate formula?

ON-basis

I do not understnad. the coordinate system in spherical coordinate is orthogonal. @md2perpe

The basis ${ \hat r, \hat\theta, \hat\phi }$ is orthogonal and each of these vectors has size 1. But $u^i$ in the tensor formula are (in the case of spherical coordinates) coefficients relative the orthogonal, but not normalized, basis ${ \hat r, r\hat\theta, r\sin\theta,\hat\phi }.$

Assuming that only r component of the velocity is not zero, the non-normalized velocity is the same as the normalized velocity. Am I wrong? @md2perpe

You are right, and I haven't investigated the error well enough. Where did you find the formula $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \textbf{u} = (\frac{\partial u_i}{\ell_i \partial x_i}- u_k \Gamma_{ii}^k)$?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/546749/calculate-the-expression-of-divergence-in-spherical-coordinates-r-theta-var @md2perpe

I don't find the formula there.

I messed up a negative sign! @md2perpe

@md2perpe I have corrected the question. Could you please have a look and see if you kniow where the extra factor $1/r$ is missing?

@md2perpe Does your following statement apply to tensors as well? "But $^$
in the tensor formula are (in the case of spherical coordinates) coefficients relative the orthogonal, but not normalized, basis ${̂ ,̂ ,sin̂ }$. For example is $\sigma^{\theta \phi}$ the coefficient of $r^2 \sin \theta \hat{\theta} \hat{\phi}$?

yes meant the second one, so divergence of the vector
@IZukaI

In spherical coordinates,
$\mathbf x = (x,y,z) = (r\sin\theta\cos\phi, r\sin\theta\sin\phi, r\cos\theta).$
Let us introduce three bases ($\alpha=r,\theta,\phi$):

$\mathbf{e}_\alpha = \frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial \alpha}$ giving
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf e_r &= (\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta) \\
\mathbf e_\theta &= (r\cos\theta\cos\phi, r\cos\theta\sin\phi, -r\sin\theta) \\
\mathbf e_\phi &= (-r\sin\theta\sin\phi, r\sin\theta\cos\phi, 0)
\end{align}$$

$\mathbf{e}^\alpha = \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \mathbf x}:=\nabla\alpha$ giving
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf e^r &= (\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta) \\
\mathbf e^\theta &= (\frac1r\cos\theta\cos\phi, \frac1r\cos\theta\sin\phi, -\frac1r\sin\theta) \\
\mathbf e^\phi &= (-\frac1{r\sin\theta}\sin\phi, \frac1{r\sin\theta}\cos\phi, 0)
\end{align}$$

$\hat\alpha:=\hat{\mathbf e}_\alpha = \mathbf e_\alpha/|\mathbf e_\alpha| = \mathbf e^\alpha/|\mathbf e^\alpha|$ giving
$$\begin{align}
\hat r := \hat{\mathbf e}_r &= (\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta) \\
\hat\theta := \hat{\mathbf e}_\theta &= (\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi, -\sin\theta) \\
\hat\phi := \hat{\mathbf e}_\phi &= (\sin\phi, \cos\phi, 0)
\end{align}$$


Note that in this case, $\mathbf e_\alpha$ and $\mathbf e^\alpha$ are parallel, so any can be used to define $\hat\alpha.$ This is only the case when the metric tensor $g_{\alpha\beta}$ is diagonal.
The coefficients of a vector $\mathbf u$ with respect to the different bases will be denoted by

$u^\alpha$ for basis $\mathbf e_\alpha,$
$u_\alpha$ for basis $\mathbf e^\alpha,$
$\hat u_\alpha$ for basis $\hat{\mathbf e}_\alpha$.

(Yes, the indices shall have opposite position for basis and coefficients in case 1 and 2.)
It should be noted that $\mathbf e^\alpha = g^{\alpha\beta}\mathbf e_\beta$ and $\mathbf e_\alpha = g_{\alpha\beta}\mathbf e^\beta.$ This implies $u_\alpha = g_{\alpha\beta} u^\beta$ and $u^\alpha = g^{\alpha\beta} u_\beta.$
The $u^\alpha$ defined above are the values used in the equation
$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf u = \partial_\alpha u^\alpha + \Gamma^\alpha_{\alpha\beta} u^\beta.$$
The $\hat u_\alpha$ are the values used in the formula
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf u = {1 \over r^2}{\partial \left( r^2 A_r \right) \over \partial r}
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta} \left(  A_\theta\sin\theta \right)
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial A_\varphi \over \partial \varphi}.
$$
Note that
$$
u^r = \hat u_r, \quad
u^\theta = \frac1r \hat u_\theta, \quad
u^\phi = \frac1{r\sin\theta} \hat u_\phi.
$$
I find that
$$
\Gamma^r = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -r & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -r \sin^2\theta
\end{pmatrix}
,\quad
\Gamma^\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/r & 0 \\
1/r & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
,\quad
\Gamma^\phi = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1/r \\
0 & 0 & \cot\theta \\
1/r & \cot\theta & 0
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$
The divergence thus is
$$\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\mathbf u
&= (\partial_r u^r + \Gamma^r_{r\alpha} u^\alpha)
+ (\partial_\theta u^\theta + \Gamma^\theta_{\theta\alpha} u^\alpha)
+ (\partial_\phi u^\phi + \Gamma^\phi_{\phi\alpha} u^\alpha) 
\\
&= (\partial_r u^r + \Gamma^r_{rr} u^r + \Gamma^r_{r\theta} u^\theta + \Gamma^r_{r\phi} u^\phi)
+ (\partial_\theta u^\theta + \Gamma^\theta_{\theta r} u^r + \Gamma^\theta_{\theta\theta} u^\theta + \Gamma^\theta_{\theta\phi} u^\phi)
+ (\partial_\phi u^\phi + \Gamma^\phi_{\phi r} u^r + \Gamma^\phi_{\phi\theta} u^\theta + \Gamma^\phi_{\phi\phi} u^\phi)
\\
&= (\partial_r u^r)
+ (\partial_\theta u^\theta + \frac1r u^r)
+ (\partial_\phi u^\phi + \frac1r u^r + \cot\theta \, u^\theta)
\\
&= \left(\partial_r \hat u_r\right)
+ \left(\partial_\theta (\frac1r \hat u_\theta) + \frac1r \hat u_r\right)
+ \left(\partial_\phi (\frac1{r\sin\theta}\hat u_\phi) + \frac1r \hat u_r + \cot\theta \frac1r\hat u_\theta\right)
\\
&= \left(\partial_r \hat u_r + \frac2r \hat u_r \right)
+ \left(\partial_\theta (\frac1r \hat u_\theta) + \cot\theta \frac1r\hat u_\theta \right)
+ \partial_\phi (\frac1{r\sin\theta}\hat u_\phi)
\\
&= \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r (r^2 \hat u_r)
+ \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \partial_\theta (\sin\theta \, \hat u_\theta)
+ \frac1{r\sin\theta} \partial_\phi \hat u_\phi
\end{align}$$
in accordance with the formula given in tables.

You have a correct expression for the divergence but the formula for the divergence found in most textbooks / wikipedia articles assumes that you are using the orthonormal spherical basis rather than the holonomic basis which is only orthogonal but must be normalized. We can simply modify your velocity field by normalizing thusly;
$$\textbf{u}=u^re_r+u^{\theta}e_{\theta}+u^{\phi}e_{\phi}=u^r\partial_r+\frac{u^{\theta}}{r}\partial_{\theta}+\frac{u^{\phi}}{r\sin{\theta}}\partial_{\phi}=\tilde u^r\partial_r+\tilde u^{\theta}\partial_{\theta}+\tilde u^{\phi}\partial_{\phi}$$
Now applying your given expression yields;
$$\nabla \cdot \textbf{u}=\nabla_k \space \tilde u^k=\partial_k\tilde u^k+\tilde u^j\Gamma_{kj}^{k}=\partial_{\theta}\bigg(\frac{u^{\theta}}{r}\bigg)+\frac{u^{\theta}}{r}\Gamma_{k\theta}^{k}$$
$$\therefore \nabla \cdot \textbf{u}=\frac{1}{r}(\partial_{\theta}u^{\theta}+u^{\theta}\cot{\theta})$$
as expected.

Thanks, but I cannot see how you wrote the velocity in terms of partial derivatives instead of unit vectors (second equality in your first equation). Can you explain what that means?

@questionerno8. Do you understand now why I was talking about normalized and non-normalized bases?

I think so, thank you very much it was very helpful. Does your explanation apply to contravarient tensors too? @md2perpe

@questionerno8. Yes, the basis for contravariant tensors is also non-ON in general.
